# How to combine filters from two different sources & return as a single on in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Following is the filtering techinique I'm using to filter out storeItems using filters from two different sources.

filtersFromSource1 is one source which contains a lot of filtering params & like wise filtersFromSource2 is another source which contains another set of filtering params. (Please don't worry about that_).

My question is about how can I combine/concat results from these two separate sources and return as a single stream/return.

Currently I've two approaches.

This is the first one.

```js
const getFiltered = (filtersFromSource1, filtersFromSource2) => {
  return storeItems.filter((storeItem) => {
    return Object.keys(filtersFromSource1).every((k) => {
      return filtersFromSource1[k].every((filter) => {
        if (filter.param1) {
          return filter.param1
            .toString()
            .toLocaleLowerCase()
            .includes(filter.trim().toLocaleLowerCase());
        }

        //   ...some other filterings from source1 todo here
        return storeItem && Object.keys(filtersFromSource2).every((k) => {
          return filtersFromSource2[k].every((filter) => {
            if (filter.param1) {
              return filter.param1
                .toString()
                .toLocaleLowerCase()
                .includes(filter.trim().toLocaleLowerCase());
            }

            // ...some other filterings from source2 todo here
            return storeItem
          })
        })
      })
    })
  }
```

This is the second one.

```js
const getFiltered = (filtersFromSource1, filtersFromSource2) => {
  return storeItems.filter((storeItem) => {
    return Object.keys(filtersFromSource1).every((k) => {
      return filtersFromSource1[k].every((filter) => {
        if (filter.param1) {
          return filter.param1
            .toString()
            .toLocaleLowerCase()
            .includes(filter.trim().toLocaleLowerCase());
        }

        //   ...some other filterings from source1 todo here
        return storeItem

      })
    }) && Object.keys(filtersFromSource2).every((k) => {
      return filtersFromSource2[k].every((filter) => {
        if (filter.param1) {
          return filter.param1
            .toString()
            .toLocaleLowerCase()
            .includes(filter.trim().toLocaleLowerCase());
        }

        // ...some other filterings from source2 todo here
        return storeItem
      })
    })
  }
```

I just want to know whether there is a better way of doing this. (or like a industry standard method for combine filtering options.)

**Remember source1 and source2 are two different filtering sources with different params**

I'm using this technique in an angular app. So if there is anything that is angular specific/related please mention that also.

**If there is a better way of doing this using other third party libraries like lodash or ramda, please suggest that also**

It will be helpful!

Comment: can you please provide a sample filtersFromSource1, filtersFromSource2 and storeItems data.

Comment: It's just some key value pairs.

Comment: it would be helpful if you provide a sample input and the output your require.

Comment: then maybe you could combine both filters first (using spread operator) and then you can run the filtering only once, instead of running the same logic twice.

Comment: Pretty much the code is repeating in both of them. So might wanna create a function to make it re-usable.

Comment: Basically filter works on boolean basis so if you want passed ones from both then you should use OR statement like: `.filter(storeItem => filterFunc(storeItem, filterSettings1) || filterFunc(storeItem, filterSettings2))`